# Angular 2+ without routing in ASP.Net MVC application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular

I have to work in ASP.Net MVC content management system.  As part of the this, ASP.Net MVC has to control the routing because it's integral to how the content is managed.  It does full-page reloads so I'm not building a single-page-app.

I'd like to use Angular 2+ (currently trying version 4) as my front-end framework so that I can leverage the component architecture, binding, Typescript, unit testing etc.  However, I have no need for the routing.

My intention is to compile the Angular app once and add the appropriate JS and CSS assets on ASP.Net MVC layout page.  Then each page where Angular is required, I would add the bootstrap component and then nest the other components (no `router-outlet`).

Unfortunately, it appears that it won't work without routing.

Here's some of my code.

**_Layout.cshtml**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Dist/vendor.css" />
</head>
<body>
    @RenderBody()
    <script src="~/Dist/vendor.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Dist/main-client.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**app.component.html**

`<div></div>`

**Controller View (Index.cshtml)**

```
<app>
    <test-component>
    </test-component>
</app>
```

**Output**

Viewing the HTML source in Chrome shows the same HTML in the Razor view.

However, inspecting the page with Chrome Dev Tools has the following.  Note: there are no errors in the console.

`<app ng-version="4.4.6"><div></div></app>`

The `app` element gets rendered bu the `test-component` element does not (HTML from `test-component.component.html` does not get substituted into the page).  My guess is because Angular 2+ requires a `router-outlet` component.

Is it possible to use Angular 2+ without the routing?

Comment: it's possible to have Angular without router. What errors are you getting?

Comment: There's no error

Comment: My feedback. Why not just use MVC that 100% fulfill your "component architecture, binding, unit testing " requirements. Setting up angular on each page load will make your pages slow as angular app has to load from scratch. Also using Angular in non - SPA could be a very wrong decision. Since Tech should be chosen as per need and not by availability of new tech.

Comment: Did you manage to do this?

Comment: @Gillardo, we didn't get it working and ended-up using React instead